# Javascript - How to add OR extend a function to an existing function

Tags: javascript, function, p5.js

I'm working in JS with [P5.JS](https://p5js.org/) and a library to generate a Gui called [p5.gui](https://github.com/bitcraftlab/p5.gui). This library is a sort of a wrapper for another library called [QuickSettings](https://github.com/bit101/quicksettings).

Alright, so this p5.js library is sort of alright, but it lacks functionality. I want to add some functions to it since they are supported by quicksettings, but not by p5.gui.

For example, I want to be able to add a save or reset Button to the gui menu.
I've hard coded it into the p5.gui library and it words great. This is the code:

```
  this.addButton = function(name, callback) {
    qs.addButton( name, callback );
  };
```

But what if some time passes and I forget I hardcoded it into the library and the library gets updated. I'll lose my code...

[This is the complete (original) code of p5.gui.](https://github.com/bitcraftlab/p5.gui/blob/master/libraries/p5.gui.js)

And this is, in reference and stripped where I put my code:

```
  (function() {

    function QSGui(label, parent, sketch) {
      
      // my code
      this.addButton = function(name, callback) {
        qs.addButton( name, callback );
      };
      // end my code

    }

  })();
```

### The question

So, my question would be if there is a way to add code to it or extend to it from my own file/script.
I'm not familiar enough with JS to do this. I saw I can't call `QSGui()` directly from another file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of the p5.gui library, I found this line:

```js
// proxy all functions of quicksettings
this.prototype = qs;
```

This means that you shouldn't have to define your own `addButton()` function. If the `QuickSettings` class has an `addButton()` function, then you should be able to call `addButton()` on an instance of `QSGui` directly. You can get an instance of `QSGui` by calling the `createGui()` function.

Something like this:

```js
var gui = createGui('My awesome GUI');
gui.addButton(...);
```

Comment: I've tried this indeed, but I get this in the console: `TypeError: gui.addButton is not a function`

Comment: @Tim Are you sure you're using the correct version of the underlying `QuickSettings` library? Do other functions work?

Comment: [I've made a codePen sketch to show a working example](https://codepen.io/TimRR/pen/qBBGxQQ?editors=1111) As you can see in the browser console (not the codepen console) it returns this `TypeError: gui.addButton is not a function`

Comment: But I have to say, now I'm more in it for the learning. Because I'm thinking I might switch from `p5.gui` to `dat.gui` It looks better on the eye. Plus I wont have the same pain working with is as `p5.gui`

Comment: @Tim I believe you that you're getting an error. I'm just wondering if it's related to versioning of the `QuickSettings` library? Where in the `QuickSettings` reference do you see the `addButton()` function? Do other functions work?

Comment: I have the function from the ref sheet on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/bit101/quicksettings#adding-controls) . And I get the js from the CDN repo from their ref doc `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quicksettings@latest/quicksettings.min.js`

Comment: I have now changed the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/TimRR/pen/qBBGxQQ?editors=1111) to illustrate the p5.gui and the quicksetting.js code side by side. They both run the same code, to illustrate the `addeButton()` and a random other function.